# Is it possible to show a tooltip on Angular PrimeNg multiselect chips?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an Angular multiselect with `display="chip"` option. I want to show a tooltip when users hover over multiselect chips (The tooltip text must vary depending on which chip he hovers over. For example, I'd like the tooltip text to simply repeat the chip text).
I already have **TooltipModule** included.

Here is a simple Starblitz project with a working multiselect and a working (separate) tooltip.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-update-model-fix-prvwjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Please advise how to proceed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the selected item template:

```html
<p-multiSelect
  #multiSelect
  [options]="cities"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCities2"
  defaultLabel="Select a City"
  optionLabel="name"
  display="chip"
>
  <ng-template let-value pTemplate="selectedItems">
    <div *ngFor="let item of value; let i = index" class="p-multiselect-token">
      <span
        class="p-multiselect-token-label"
        [pTooltip]="multiSelect.findLabelByValue(item)"
      >
        {{ multiSelect.findLabelByValue(item) }}
      </span>

      <span
        *ngIf="!multiSelect.disabled"
        class="p-multiselect-token-icon pi pi-times-circle"
        (click)="multiSelect.removeChip(item, $event)"
      ></span>
    </div>

    <ng-container *ngIf="!value || value.length === 0">
      {{ multiSelect.placeholder || multiSelect.defaultLabel || 'empty' }}
    </ng-container>
  </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-update-model-fix-1fjtp7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

The exact template can be copied from the PrimeNG's [Github](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/f0b6fc98d08285a61e63a0200cd410f75f195414/src/app/components/multiselect/multiselect.ts#L142-L146).

Comment: I ran into the same question. Now only if i could find some way to get the entire item back (not just .findLabelByValue(item)), so i can base the styling of the chip on some attribute the item has.
{ label: 'MyLabel', code: '123', myAttribute: 'red'}

Comment: @Koesper, you could either (A) copy the [`findLabelByValue`](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/f0b6fc98d08285a61e63a0200cd410f75f195414/src/app/components/multiselect/multiselect.ts#L1056-L1075) method and adjust it so that it returns the entire object (you'll need to get `multiSelect` via [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and pass it to the method) or (B) prepare a `Map<string, { myAttribute: string }>` and use `map[item]` for styling. Option B is more performat and would be my preferred approach.